# MySQL Optimize Nested SELECT and INSERT Statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find any ways to optimize this statement:

```
INSERT INTO achievements 
(
    nick, cost, achievement_type, announced_in_chat, shown_on_stream, dt
)

SELECT nick, 2000, 0, TRUE, FALSE, NOW() 
FROM points_log

WHERE nick NOT IN 
(
    SELECT nick from achievements
    WHERE achievement_type = 0 AND stream_online = TRUE
)
GROUP BY nick HAVING SUM(amount) >= 2000;
```

The goal is to find people who have scored 2000 points (SUM(amount)) from the points_log and are also not in achievements (nick NOT IN). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the achievements and points_log tables:

```
mysql> describe achievements;
+-------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| nick              | char(25)              | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| cost              | decimal(8,4)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| achievement_type  | tinyint(3) unsigned   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| announced_in_chat | tinyint(1)            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| shown_on_stream   | tinyint(1)            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dt                | datetime              | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)


mysql> describe points_log;
+-------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| nick              | char(25)              | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| amount            | decimal(10,4)         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| stream_online     | tinyint(1)            | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| modification_type | tinyint(3) unsigned   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| dt                | datetime              | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: I would get rid of "WHERE [...] NOT IN", rather use "LEFT JOIN [...] WHERE [...] ISNULL" because it's much faster

Comment: @valicu2000 Can you explain? I'm not sure how to craft that statement.

Comment: Something like: INSERT INTO achievements 
(
    nick, cost, achievement_type, announced_in_chat, shown_on_stream, dt
)

(
SELECT p.nick, 2000, 0, TRUE, FALSE, NOW() 
FROM points_log p 
LEFT JOIN 
achievements a 
ON 
p.nick=a.nick 
WHERE 
a.nick ISNULL 
AND 
a.achievement_type = 0 
AND 
a.stream_online = TRUE
)

GROUP BY nick HAVING SUM(amount) >= 2000;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimizing the `insert` is really just optimizing the query:

```
SELECT nick, 2000, 0, TRUE, FALSE, NOW() 
FROM points_log
WHERE nick NOT IN (SELECT nick 
                   from achievements
                   WHERE achievement_type = 0 AND stream_online = TRUE
                  )
GROUP BY nick
HAVING SUM(amount) >= 2000;
```

I might turn this query "inside out":

```
SELECT pl.nick, 2000, 0, TRUE, FALSE, NOW() 
FROM points_log pl LEFT JOIN
     achievements a
     ON a.nick = pl.nick AND a.achievement_type = 0 AND a.stream_online = TRUE
WHERE a.nick IS NULL
GROUP BY nick
HAVING SUM(amount) >= 2000;
```

For this query, you want an index on `achievements(nick, achievement_type, stream_online`.

You *claim* in the question that you simply want to avoid achievements for `nick` in `achievements`.  The easiest way to do *that* is with a query:

```
INSERT INTO achievements(nick, cost, achievement_type, announced_in_chat, shown_on_stream, dt)
    SELECT pl.nick, 2000, 0, TRUE, FALSE, NOW() 
    FROM points_log pl 
    GROUP BY nick
    HAVING SUM(amount) >= 2000
    ON DUPLICATE KEY SET nick = VALUES(nick);
```

And a unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_achievements_nick ON achievements(nick);
```

However, your query has additional conditions that your question doesn't address.